# Bash: Use an alias in a variable

Tags: bash, alias

I am writing a bash script that runs each of its arguments as a command. This works for commands in my `PATH`, but not for aliases. I can directly call an alias in the script, but I can't call an alias that has been passed as an argument.

The problem (I assume) is that aliases are expanded before variables. Is there a way to run aliases from a variable?

Sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: runall

shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.aliases

while (( "$#" )); do
    $1
    shift
done
```

`runall "echo test"` works, but `runall "myalias"` gives `runall: line 8: myalias: command not found`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some testing, I have concluded the following:

- Aliases only work in interactive mode (add `-i` to the shebang).
- Aliases are not evaluated when they come from an interpreted source (in this case, the variable.
- You can get bash to use the alias with `eval $1`. Note that `eval`ing anything created with a variable is dangerous, but since the whole point of the script requires arbitrary execution, I won't make too big a deal out of that.

From the bash man page:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless  the
>   expand_aliases  shell option is set using shopt (see the description of
>   shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

So you could add `shopt -s expand_aliases` instead of `-i`.

Also,

> Aliases are expanded  when  a command is read, not when it is executed.

Since variables are not expanded before the command is read, they will not be expanded further using the alias.

Comment: Nice to know. Just out of curiosity: why is it dangerous to `eval` variables?

Comment: @hesse Consider `eval "echo $1"`. Say I call `./script.sh "hello;rm -rf ~`. What gets executed? `echo hello`, followed by `rm -rf ~`. Obviously that's a contrived example, but the principle holds.

Comment: adding `eval` in front of `$1` worked, since I already had `shopt -s expand_aliases`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and managed to solve my issue by turning my aliases to functions, as described on [this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-pass-argument-to-alias-command/), which worked for me.

e.g.

```
alias lsd="ls -lash"
```

to

```
function lsd() { ls -lash; }
```